# How to execute custom script while merge two GitHub branches on the code of child branch

Tags: git, github, pipeline

I have a scenario where I have two branches in Github 'Master' & 'Dev'. We have some hard-coded environment variables defined in code, that we change manually while we merge code from the 'Dev' branch to the 'master'.

We have a shell script that we execute manually on the 'master' branch code on our system.

Can we set a process in GitHub that will execute our custom script every time on the 'dev' branch code when we push merge/push code from the 'Dev' branch to 'Master'?

If it is possible, can you also suggest which method we should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [post-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) hook. eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# 1: old ref
# 2: new ref
# 3: branch (1) or file (0)

BRANCH_NAME=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
IS_BRANCH=$3

if [ $IS_BRANCH -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "HEAD is $BRANCH_NAME"
    # do stuff for the appropriate branch
    # eg: `source $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/vars.sh`
fi
```

However, as what you want to do is set environment variables and this will run in a sub-shell this will not be able to affect the environment of your git launching shell.

You could however have a difference version of a file on each branch and simply source that file after each checkout. ie if you create a vars.sh file and it is different on dev and master then `. vars.sh` will load the right variables for whichever branch you are on.

Comment: Actually, I want to check and update the env variables automatically in merging code files while I merge the code to the master branch

Comment: `post-checkout` hook at GitHub?

Comment: Thank @phd , can you please share any sample code to test it.

Comment: @Atul My sarcastic comment means — there are no hooks at GitHub, certainly no `post-checkout` hook. You could try `post-checkout` hook locally, or you could try webhooks at GitHub or you could try Github Actions.

Comment: Thanks idea works for me, I have use 'post-merge' for my solution. But can we apply the same if we merge from github portal ?

Comment: Can you please also have a look at -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76263673/how-to-execute-hooks-via-github-portal